# What logarithmic function do windows use for the audio volume slider?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, volume

I am currently struggling with the implementation of my audio volume slider in my c++ app.

The app is able to control the windows mixer volume level and the slider has the range 0.0f to 1.0f.

The problem I am facing is that my DB values aren't equal to the DB values windows is using.

Here are some values I set with my volume slider with the resulting DB values and the ones windows is using.

[image]

Below is the function I use for calculating the audio DB level. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance!

```
    if (this->m_useAudioEndpointVolume)
    {
        const float slider_min = 0.0f;
        const float slider_max = 1.0f;
        const float logBase = 10;

        m_ignoreAudioValue = TRUE;

        if (volume >= 1.0f) {
            volume = 1.0f;
        }

        if (volume <= 0.0f) {
            volume = 0.0f;
        }

        float pfLevelMinDB = 0;
        float pfLevelMaxDB = 0;
        float pfVolumeIncrementDB = 0;
        m_pEndpointVolume->GetVolumeRange(&pfLevelMinDB, &pfLevelMaxDB, &pfVolumeIncrementDB);

        // Logarithmic formula for audio volume
        // Volume = log(((Slider.Value-Slider.Min)*(B-1))/(Slider.Max-Slider.Min) + 1)/log(B) * (Volume.Max - Volume.Min) + Volume.Min
        float calcVolume = log(((volume - slider_min)*(logBase - 1)) / (slider_max - slider_min) + 1) / log(logBase) * (pfLevelMaxDB - pfLevelMinDB) + pfLevelMinDB;

        if (volume == 0.0f) {
            m_pEndpointVolume->SetMute(TRUE, NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            m_pEndpointVolume->SetMute(FALSE, NULL);
        }

        float currentValue = 0.0f;

        m_pEndpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevel(&currentValue);

        // Todo: The calculation has to be logarithmic
        m_pEndpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevel(calcVolume, NULL);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The **IAudioEndpointVolume** has the function **SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar**. This function uses the range from 0.0 to 1.0 regarding to the MSDN documentation so you don't need to implement a logarithmic function yourself.
Seems like I overlooked this one.

Here's the current code sample I am using in case someone will need it in the future.

```
float pLevel = 0.0f;
m_pEndpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&pLevel);

// We have to set this first to TRUE to an avoid unnecessary callback
m_ignoreAudioValue = TRUE;
// Set the scalar value
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd368062(v=vs.85).aspx
m_pEndpointVolume->SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(sliderValue, NULL);

// We have to set this again to TRUE to avoid an unnecessary callback
// because the SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar triggers the OnNotify event
// and this causes the m_ignoreAudioValue to be FALSE again.
m_ignoreAudioValue = TRUE;
// If the value is higher the 0.0 unmute the master volume.
m_pEndpointVolume->SetMute(sliderValue > 0.0f ? FALSE : TRUE, NULL);

m_pEndpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&pLevel);
```

**Edit:**

It seems like Windows is using a linear volume slider. Thats the reason why 2% in Windows feels still too loud and everything above 50% isn't much of an increase anymore.

Here's a really good article about it why you should avoid it.

[Volume Controls](https://www.dr-lex.be/info-stuff/volumecontrols.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assume the following:

```
volumeMaxDB =  +5
volumeMinDB = -10
incrementDB = 5
```

To me this suggests a slider that would look something like the ascii art below. I've also shown my presumed mapping to your slider UI's scale.

```
        dB        Slider
     |  +5   <=>   1.0
     |   0
     -  -5
     |  -10  <=>   0.0
```

First, calculate the total volume range in dB (e.g. -10 to +5 is 15 dB)

```
dBRange = abs(volumeMaxDB) + abs(volumeMinDB);
```

Second, scale the current slider position dB value of 0 to dBRange. This gives the following mappings
* 0.0 -> 0
* 1.0 -> 15
* 0.5 -> 7.5

```
dB = dBRange * slider;
```

Third, shift the range up or down so that +15 becomes +5 and 0 becomes -10.

```
dB = dB - (dbRange - volumeMaxDB);
```

Finally, you may want to round to the nearest dB increment.

Extra credit: If you have control over your slider's range, you could make your life *way* simpler by just setting the min and max value the same as minDB and maxDB and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. As soon as I tried it out I will give you feedback and accept the answer.

Comment: Hello again. I tried it out. Unfortunately it's not the solution I need. This is a linear volume slider and not a logarithmic.

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer. I would point out that your question WAS about a log slider: "The problem I am facing is that my DB values aren't equal to the DB values windows is using."

Comment: Thats right but your answer was a linear function if I am right.